# Should I put the home directories on an SSD?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd, home-directory

Considering the usage of home directories under Linux, should I put them on an SSD disk along with the OS (perhaps on a separate EXT4 partition) or should I leave them on spindle?

What's your view?

Comment: There are fine reasons for either. I would just leave them in their default location.

Comment: Sorry, can you please elaborate more?

Comment: What is your primary concern with leaving the OS on an SSD, read/writes? Also, if the concern is usage, I'd want my most used files to be in the fastest place. SSD prices will be much lower by the time you need a new one (Even if that is only a couple of years)

Comment: The OS files should be mainly used in R/O mode, which is fine. Home directories instead are used in very R/W mode; I just wouldn't want to have a broken SSD, where I lose both my OS _and_ home files...

Comment: I use a 120GB SSD on my laptop, have had it for.. a year and a half now, and I am VERY write intensive. No problems yet, SSD is still in good health. You should also be backing up your files frequently.

Comment: Just bought a 1 TB SSD Samsung 840 EVO. I'll partition on 2 and leave one partition for OS, another for /home then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a ssd for 5 years (I think) and more then 40 OS installed,deleted... Still alive.  I think the best is to keep yor /home on ssd on a separate partition(assuming that space/number of partition allow this).I have a laptop that I share with coworkers, there I put /home on mmc card (most of them are win users, I don't want them to acces something in ssd). Also, for a modern OS, don't use ext2/3 because of less writes on ssd: ext4 is well optimised in kernel, fast and reliable. Some app like firefox and chrome „feel” the diference:they are much slower on hdd.
If you pay ssd, use ssd.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to do this. What's the point of having and SSD and not using it? My only concern is related to durability, because my 'old OCZ has failed me... wouldn't want neither kernel neither home to disappear... :-)